# Printing remote file using Java Script from a webpage

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, vbscript

Task I am trying to achieve: Need to print a remote file(I have the file URL which is there in different server, the URL will open / download the file) in user local system from the webpage in a J2EE application.

Description:

I am trying to print the remote file from the browser. Remote file can be any thing PDF or word or TIFF. Max cases it will be PDF.

Is this possible using JS?

I have come across some of the solutions in VBScript but I heard that VBScirtp will not work in Chrome and Firefox. This solution should support IE, chrome & Firefox

Also trying to achieve by using applet but no luck so far. Need suggestions in how to achieve this in the best way, pointing to any examples will be much helpful.

Thanks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can print remote documents directly to your local printer without having to download documents.

In the **Applet** you can write:

```
PrintService printService = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
if(service != null) {
    DocFlavor docFlawor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.PDF;
    PrintRequestAttributeSet printRequestAttributeSet = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();    
    DocPrintJob job = printService.createPrintJob();
    Doc pdf = new SimpleDoc(new URL(url).openStream(), docFlawor, null);
    job.print(pdf, printRequestAttributeSet);         
}
```

Then integrate applet into web page:

```
<applet id="printApplet" code="....PrintApplet.class" codebase="/applet" archive="printApplet.jar" ></applet>
```

Then call **Applet** from **JavaScript**:

```
<button onclick="printApplet.print('http://.......');">Print</button>
```

Comment: Hi Alexey thanks for the procedure. PDF its working fine and i could able to use images as well with the above solution, but DocFlavor dont have options to specify word document. Is there a way for printing Doc or Docx with any open source API's. I am checking Apache POI but couldn't figure out exactly how to print word document.